# Drawing on Canvas with image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video, drawing

I have a video element playing a mp4 video.
When clicking the screenshot button, it draws the current video frame on the canvas. I would then like to draw on top of the canvas.

My problem is that I can't get the cursor to align with the drawing coordinates. I have a suspicion that this is because of the way I'm setting the height and the width of the canvas to be able to draw the video frame correctly.

Minimal repro:
https://codepen.io/stiba/pen/KEBRdy

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('vid');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

var isDrawing = false;
var prevX = 0;
var prevY = 0;
var currX = 0;
var currY = 0;

function buttonClick() {
  console.log('Clicked!');
  var height = video.videoHeight;
  var width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
}

function setCoordinates(e) {
  prevX = currX;
  prevY = currY;

  var boundingClientRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var left = boundingClientRect.left;
  var top = boundingClientRect.top;

  currX = e.clientX - left;
  currY = e.clientY - top;
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  setCoordinates(e);
  isDrawing = true;
}

function mouseUp(e) {
  isDrawing = false;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) {
    return;
  }

  setCoordinates(e);
  draw();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the css styles from your canvas will fix the issue. If you need your canvas to be larger use canvas.width and canvas.height properties. Using css to control your canvas size will only increase the html element size but not the drawing surface(pixels).

css to be removed:

```
 flex: 1;
 width: 100%;
```